# Joomla 1.7 menu-type adding

Tags: joomla1.7

I created a 1.7 component using Not Webdesigns Component Creator. They saved me a bunch of time in 1.5 so now Im finally switching to 1.7 coding I used them again for the basic outline of my components.

Now everything works and installs fine. Everything shows up and Joomla finds index.php?option=com_dealers (Its called com_dealers obv.) Just when I hit menu type in the menumanagement, there is no shortcut to my component. How do I add it to that list? A simple xml etc... was enough in 1.5 but it obviously isnt now...

Greetings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, so Ill post it here, since I guess a lot of people will have this same problem using the creator.

The creator forgets one xml. Namely default.xml in site/views/COMPONENTNAME/tmpl . Add a default.xml there with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="COMPONENTNAME">
                <message>COMPONENTNAMEFront End view</message>
        </layout>
</metadata>
```